# WildFly management - list/detect REST endpoints deployed in WildFly

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, wildfly-8

Is there a way (e.g. from a WildFly management console) to list all REST endpoints deployed in WildFly? Or to list them in a log while a server is starting?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Using the `RegistryStatsResource`

With RESTEasy (that is shipped with WildFly), you could add the following to your `web.xml`:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.resources</param-name>
    <param-value>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.stats.RegistryStatsResource</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And then request the following URL:

```
http://[hostname]:[port]/[context]/[api-path]/resteasy/registry
```

Such endpoint can produce XML and JSON content. Just add the `Accept` header to the request with the desired media type:

- `application/xml`
- `application/json`

### Checking the source code

If you are interested in the source code to create your own implementation, have a look at the [`RegistryStatsResource` class on GitHub](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/master/providers/jaxb/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/stats/RegistryStatsResource.java).

The most relevant part of the source code is shown below (it's RESTEasy specific):

```java
ResourceMethodRegistry registry = (ResourceMethodRegistry) 
    ResteasyProviderFactory.getContextData(Registry.class);

for (String key : registry.getBounded().keySet()){
List<ResourceInvoker> invokers = registry.getBounded().get(key);

for (ResourceInvoker invoker : invokers) {

    if (invoker instanceof ResourceMethodInvoker) {

        ResourceMethodInvoker rm = (ResourceMethodInvoker) invoker;

        // Extract metadata from the ResourceMethodInvoker
    }
}
```

### Swagger may be an alternative

Depending on your requirements, you can use [Swagger](http://swagger.io/) to document your API. It comes with a [set of annotations](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/current/apidocs/io/swagger/annotations/package-summary.html) to describe your REST endpoints.

Then use [Swagger UI](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui) to provide a live documentation for your API.

---

<sup>**Note:** As of February 2017, looks like the [`RegistryStatsResource`](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/master/providers/jaxb/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/stats/RegistryStatsResource.java) class is completely undocumented. I occasionally discovered it when digging into the RESTEasy source code for debugging purposes. Also, I found this [JBoss EAP issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBEAP-3669) that tracks the lack of documentation for that class.</sup>

Comment: The Maven dependency is:    ````<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>````

Answer (score 4):

From the Management Console, you can view the published endpoints.

When you login as an administrator, Click the Runtime option on the top navigation bar as shown below.

[image: Sample Wildfly Page]

Click the **JAX-RS** option, then click the REST Resources option. This will display the endpoints to the far right.

Comment: Mine won't appear this option(alonside with many others). Is there a additional configuration needed to enable it?

Comment: What is missing are the actual URLs of the end points.